# QTP Keyword driven basic example

Tags: keyword, qtp

I have been looking for very basic keyword driven test..i do not understand well how you can separate the test specifically from application so its reusable. In my understanding, the QTP commands like "navigate" are keywords. But how to create my own independent ones? I would be very grateful for example of how to do that. I found either too complex or just theoretical ones.
Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know about overloading of keywords. But when i was writing test cases in QTP for automation. I used configurable navigation paths in the prop or config file n all i needed to do was call a generic function which took source n destination n using those prop files navigate to the proper location.

Comment: LOL...are you two pingponging arbitrary questions and answers to gain respect points here? Answer has nothing (?) to do with the question, is not even useful as far as I can(not) understand it. -1 just to be mean this time.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I do not have a good experience with QTP, but just worked a little on it. Probably i did not got the question right, i just wrote my experience in case it would be of any help. Thanks for being sooo encouraging.

Comment: The encouragement is to improve the question so one has a chance to understand what you did, and how it helped in the keyword driven testing approach. Until then, the fact that the answer is accepted is just -- strange.

Comment: And note that that downvote of mine did cost me 1 worthful respect point :)

Answer (score 2):

In QTP jargon a *keyword* is a combination of a test object and method (see the *available keywords* pane).

Keyword driven testing is used to mean creating a test without recording. You can create test objects in one of the following methods and then construct a test from these test objects.

1. Descriptive programming
2. Manually create test objects in the object repository (using the *create new* command)
3. Using **navigate and learn**
4. Record and discard the script
5. Import from XML

Answer (score 0):

*Example of a test.*
Go to a web store. Search for a product. Login. Buy. Logout.
(The test is already broken down to keywords)

*The simplest approach.*
Simply write a list of operations for the corresponding objects. E.g. a simplified variant:

```
Browser.Open(WebStoreURL)
Browser.Sync
Browser.Page.WebEdit(SearchBoxName).Type "something I want"
' then login, buy, logout using the same approach
' add verification points where needed
```

In the end you have quite a long script.
If you need to write another script that tests a similar case, you need to repeat most of the actions above.

*Another approach.*
To avoid duplication, you can, for example, create such functions/actions: Login, Logout, Search(product_name), etc. And then create scripts using these actions/functions, i.e. keywords:

```
Login
Search "something I want"
Buy
Logout
```

It is an example of a keyword driven approach. It works on a higher level of abstraction then QTP commands.

The approach is not limited to using QTP functions. Keywords can be implemented as words in an Excel file.